# HTTP 400 - Hard to understand error code with minimal description

Tags: http, tcp, http-headers, http-post

All,

My requirement is fairly simple. I have to perform a simple HTTP POST to an IP:port combination. I used simple socket programming to do that and I have been successful in sending across my request to them and also get back response from them. The only problem being that the response is always a HTTP 400: Bad Request followed by my HTTP POST message. I am not sure if the problem is with the client or the server. My only guess being that there might be a problem with my data that I am sending. This is what my POST looks like

```
POST /<Server Tag> HTTP/5.1
Content-Length: xxx


--Content--
```

and the response from the server looks something like this

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: xxx

--Same content that I sent them--
```

I was not sure If I could put in the IP of the server here so kept myself to using . I am pretty sure that the problem would not be there since I get back some response from the server and confident about the connection. Can someone help me ?

PS: Some pointers about my POST:

1) HTTP 5.1 was requested by the server and I am not sure if that is correct
2) I have played around with the number of line spaces after the content length. I have tried giving one and two lines. Not sure if that would make a difference. On wireshark though I see a difference with the number of line spaces as with a single line space the protocol is specified as TCP but with two it changes to HTTP. The response is always received on HTTP protocol. Some explanation on the difference would also help

Thanks

edit: the other thing that confuses me is that the response has a HTTP 1.1 and not a 5.1 that I had sent. I have also tried changing my post to 1.1 with no success

edit2: Based on suggestion form fvu and others, I used WebClient to Upload my request. Still got back a 400. The header that was generated by the WebClient looks like this

```
POST <server tag> HTTP/1.1
Host: <IP:PORT>
Content-Length: 484
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The issue I see with this might be that the server was not expecting all the details in the header. The server has requested only the `Content-Length` from us. Would that be a problem?
Thanks

Comment: If your request contains the header "Content Length: <number>" then this is a problem; it should be "Content-Length: <number>". You should probably use an actual HTTP client library rather than trying to write HTTP yourself though; it's almost always easier. (HTTP/5.1 is nonsense too.)

Comment: HTTP 5.1 is most definitely wrong.  Also curious as to why you don't just use a ready-made API for http, you risk wasting tons of time on the many subtleties of http and socket communication, time that you'd better invest in the actual functionality you're delivering.

Comment: @JamesAylett: My bad. it was `Content-Length` and not `Content Length.

Comment: As a general rule: 4xx = client did something wrong, 5xx = server has a problem.

Comment: @All: Any suggestions on the APIs that can be used?

Comment: What programming language are you using?  There's literally thousands of 'em

Comment: C#, I probably guess anything for the .NET framework would work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33789/discussion-between-ron-and-fvu)

Comment: @All: Webclient gives us a header that has a lot of extra information which I think might gives us back a 400. Please refer to the edit in the question

Comment: Are you sure that `POST` method is allowed on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a debugging proxy to view a client request and a server response to figure out what your client socket program needs to do.

But first you need to create a simple web page that a browser displays, allows you to do a POST from the browser to the web server, and get a simple response back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. HTTP/5.1 is either wrong or misused by the programmer of the server application
2. You should get a valid example from the server api to check your protocol implementation first.